# ReactNative RCTResponseSenderBlock or Callback with return value

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

We have a React Native Module, with iOS and Android support.
At some point, the native iOS and Android components will pass a parameter to JavaScript and ask for info.

We saw in the docs that we can use Callbacks. Knowing that callbacks are functions, it can takes parameters and return values.

*For simplicity, I'll share one method from the [React Native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#callbacks) to demonstrate our problem.*

```c
// iOS
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(findEvents:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  NSArray *events = ...
  id result = callback(@[[NSNull null], events]);
//  ~~~^~~~
//  This is not allowed, RCTResponseSenderBlock returns void
}
```

```java
// Android
@ReactMethod
  public void findEvents(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
    Event events[] = ...
    try {
      Object result = successCallback.invoke(events);
//         ~~~~^~~~~
// This is not allowed, Callback returns void
    } catch (IllegalViewOperationException e) {
      errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

In this example, we pass `events`, and ask for result from JavaScript. In JavaScript, code should be:

```js
CalendarManager.findEvents((error, events) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    return { "success": true } // we want to receive this in Native code.
  }
});
```

We also looked at Promises and Event Emitters. But none of them designed for returns.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: While I haven't tried it. I highly suspect this method is the solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Base/RCTBridge.m#L395

Comment: did not have `RCTResponseSenderBlock` in it.